# typescript でキーをプログラムで指定しながら export したい

Tags: javascript, typescript

今、 firebase functions を typescript で記述しています。その結果、例えば以下のような index.ts ができあがります。

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const func1 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => ...)
export const func2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => ...)
```

今、 functions に載せる載せないはデプロイの問題なので、この構造を別ファイルに定義しておいて、それを利用して上記と同等の export を index.ts で実行したいと思っています。

具体的には、

```js
// myfunctions.ts
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const MyFunctions = {
  func1: functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => ...),
  func2: functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => ...)
};

export default MyFunctions;
```

に関数定義を切り出せたとしたとき、

```js
// index.ts
import MyFunctions from 'myfunctions';

// MyFunctions を利用して以下と等価な export を行いたい
// export const func1 = MyFunctions.func1
// export const func2 = MyFunctions.func2
```

のコメント部分を、 myfunctions 定義におけるキーのの増減に従って勝手に調整されるようにしたいと思っています。これは、どうやったら実現できますでしょうか。

**追記**

勝手に調整とは、例えば func3 を生やしたいときに、その際に必要になるのは myfunctions.ts の  MyFunctions のオブジェクトだけであり、 index.ts は特に触らずとも func3 を index.ts にて export したことになること、です。

Comment: 「勝手に調整」とはどのような挙動を想定していますか？文脈からだと読み取りづらいので具体的に説明してみてください。

Comment: @himenon 追記しました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自分が欲しかったものは、 `export =` の記法である、ということに気付きました。

```
// myfunctions.ts
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export = {
  func1: functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => ...),
  func2: functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => ...)
}
```

これを用いて、

```
import functions = require("./myfunctions");

export = functions
```

Answer (score 1):

index.tsを経由してmyfunctinons.tsの実装をexportしたいとお見受けしました。
スマートな回答としては以下のようになります。

```
// myfunctions.ts
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const func1 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => ...);
export const func2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => ...);
```

index.tsからexportする方法は以下の3通り

```
// パターン1: named exportを利用する
// https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export-all-as-x
export * as MyFunctions from "./myfunctions";

// パターン2: myfunctionsそのものをそのままexportする。使う側でどういった名前にするかを委ねる
export * from "./myfunctions";

// パターン3: named exportを使わない場合
import * as MyFunctions from "./myfunctions";
export { MyFunctions };
```

`MyFunctions`というオブジェクトを生成せずとも、importする側で名前を決めることができます。